# How to use bash/sed to loop over numbers and launch multiple programs with a delay

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I would like to accomplish the following via bash/sed:

#1. set i = 1 and j = 34

#2. Employ sed to modify my script (myscript.txt) using the values of i and j from step #1

#3. run a program that uses myscript.txt

#4. Employ sed again to change myscript.txt to its original values

#5. wait 5s

#6. increment i and j by 34 and repeat steps #2, #3, #4 and #5.

What I have gotten so far is that the code launches the program only once. Any suggestions?

```
j = 1
for i in {1..1021..34}; do
    echo "Number: $i"
    j=$(($i+33))
    echo "Number: $j"
    cd "/path_to_my_script/"
    sed -i "s/local min = 123456789/local min = ${i}/g" myscript.txt  &&
    sed -i "s/local max = 123456789/local max = ${j}/g" myscript.txt  &&
    run program using myscript.txt  && sleep 5s &&
    sed -i "s/local min = ${i}/local min = 123456789/g" myscript.txt   &&
    sed -i "s/local max = ${j}/local max = 123456789/g" myscript.txt 
done
```

Comment: FYI you can do both substitutions in a single call to `sed`, with multiple `-e` options.

Comment: I can't see a reason why this would only launch the program once.

Comment: Why not use command line options or environment variables to pass the values of variables?  What is the shebang in your script? Is it `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning to see everything it's doing.

Comment: You don't need to do `cd` every time through the loop. Do it once before the loop.

Comment: Instead of modifying the file and then modifying it back, I suggest you write the output to a different file and use that when you run the program.

Comment: Amazing tips, guys. Let me try them.

Comment: Output in a different file or `run program using <(sed ... myscript.txt)`

Comment: @Jacob Please [edit] your question and add your updated scripts there instead of using comments. You can answer your own question, but you should add more details about the problem you found and how you solved it. I doubt that there is a problem with `faketime` by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the great help provided the the StackOverflow community, I have been able to solve the problem. The final script can be represented by:

```
cd "/path_to_my_script/"
j = 1
for i in {1..1021..34}; do
    echo "Number: $i"
    j=$(($i+33))
    echo "Number: $j"
    sed -e "s/local min = 123456789/local min = ${i}/g" original_script.txt > script_to_run.txt 
    sed -i "s/local max = 123456789/local max = ${j}/g" script_to_run.txt 
    run program using script_to_run.txt  & sleep 5s
   done
```

Source of the problem: I was using a trial version of a program that expired a few days ago. To use it, I had to use faketime. After purchasing the full version, there was no need for faketime and the code worked perfectly. Besides, the code has been changes, since I wanted exactly how Bodo stated below:  "start program in the background without waiting and at the same time sleep for 5 seconds"

Comment: You should add an explanation what was the cause of the problem and what are the important changes. In `run program using script_to_run.txt  & sleep 5s` you used a single `&` instead of the original double `&&`. Is this change intentional? (The former means "start your program in the background without waiting and at the same time sleep for 5 seconds" while the latter means "run the program and if it finished with success sleep for 5 seconds".)